# How to by-pass proxy for a few URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, proxy

My Web application is using a few backend APIs. I want to use proxy configured in web.config for 2 APIs but for 3rd API I want to bypass this proxy. The best solution for me is via web.config.

How to do it? 
Best solution is via web.config.

Comment: Use following https://stackoverflow.com/a/61275774/1662459

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default Proxy how bypass most url and only apply to a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295285/default-proxy-how-bypass-most-url-and-only-apply-to-a-few)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found solution:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" >
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://proxy.ccc.com:911" bypassonlocal="true" />
      <bypasslist >
         <add address="aaa.bbb.com" /> <!-- url not using proxy -->
     </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: My app utilized multiple third party URLs, few requires proxy few not. Above is just for adding bypass list