# Default Proxy how bypass most url and only apply to a few

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, biztalk

In our BizTalk Server, administrators have installed a proxy.

This proxy is only for a few URLs and the most URLs have to bypass it.

We set on BTSNTSvc64.exe.config the property:

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">  
                               <proxy usesystemdefault="True"
                                               proxyaddress="http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8080"
                                               bypassonlocal="True" />
</defaultProxy>
```

How to set the bypasslist to include the most URLs that don't need a proxy and remove only a few that need a proxy?

Comment: So...more weird decisions by "Administrators".  Do they really need to do this?  Can't they just deny all external access and map/proxy at the network level?

Comment: I know, but ... the only solution that I have at this moment is implement on BizTalk config, the map/proxy at the network level is not an option :-(

Answer (score 2):

How about adding everything to the bypass list and the remove the urls you want to use the proxy?

```
<bypasslist>
<add address='.*' />
<remove address='my url' />
</bypasslist>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following regex in the `<bypasslist>`

```
^((?!domain1)(?!domain2\.com).)*$
```

It will take all domain except defined above

```
www.contoso.com
api.contoso.com
www.domain1.com
sub.domain1.net
http2://www.domain2.com
sub.domain2.com
sub.domain2.edu
http://sub.domain2.net
sub.domain1.edu
http://sub.domain1.net
10.10.10.10
192.168.1.1
www.microsoft.com
api.google.com
```

Have created a test: https://regexr.com/52o30

Eg:

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true">
  <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://2.3.4.5:6789" bypassonlocal="True" />
  <bypasslist>
    <add address="^((?!domain1)(?!domain2\.com).)*$" />
  </bypasslist>
</defaultProxy>
```

Here, `domain1` will be completely ignored with any TLD, but `domain2` will be ignored only when full domain name is present like `domain2.com`, (*with any preceding characters or pre-domain for both domains*).

Answer (score 0):

So, this is not your problem and it's not a BizTalk issue.  It's the Administrator's issue.

You need to ask them how to configure apps to bypass their proxy.  Consider, it wouldn't be very useful if any person could just bypass it with a config file.

Meaning, they need to tell you how to exempt specific apps from whatever proxy process they're using.  If they refuse, it's still *not your problem*, it's for your manager or the business owner to address.