# Use WebProxy for a HttpClient I don't control

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, httpclient

There is a library that initializes it's own private HttpClient. I need to use a *specific* proxy ip and port when a certain URL is used within that HttpClient.
Because the library is third party, I cannot send it a Handler and set a proxy for it.

One solution I thought of is perhaps to use the [defaultProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings) in the app.config. The issue is that I only one particular URL wildcard to go through this proxy, and all other URLs to be proxy-free.

With DefaultProxy there is the notion of a `bypasslist` but I basically need the opposite, a white list where the proxy is active.

Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish what we need? Using any kind of software outside of code isntfeasible (like a debugging proxy/fiddler)

Given the url we want the proxy active for is something like `https://www.que.dok.com/services/*`
Is it possible to feed regex to bypasslist that bypasses every URL unless it matches, if so what would the regex be?

Comment: Write you own proxy, and point the library towards that. Then you can control it completely

Comment: I have my own proxy through squid, are you saying that every web request should go through the proxy and just have it be active when its a certain URL. Make it a proxy problem rather than code?  This would be OK but I don't want all the overhead of all my traffic to go through the proxy when they need it. There are probably 1000 requests to various URLs the app goes through, only 10 or so that match the regex supplied in OP need to go through a proxy

Comment: you could maybe think about something like proxifier.  It will intercept outbound connections, and dependent on certain criteria can pass via a defined proxy.

Comment: p.s. "write you own proxy" is not good advice.  These things are not simple. That's like "write you own database engine"

Comment: Read following for generic web.config configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61275774/1662459

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use .NET Framework and the library uses [WinINet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/portal) HTTP stack implementation (`HttpClientHandler` on .NET Framework), you can set `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` property to a custom `IWebProxy` decorator that uses regular expression to decide when to invoke wrapped `IWebProxy` instance. Consider creating custom branch of the library codebase specific to your needs otherwise.

Example implementation:

```
public class FilteredProxy : IWebProxy
{
    readonly IWebProxy _wrapped;
    readonly Regex _useFor;
    public FilteredProxy(IWebProxy wrapped, Regex useFor)
    {
        _wrapped = wrapped;
        _useFor = useFor;
    }

    public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
    {
        return !_useFor.IsMatch(host.ToString()) || _wrapped.IsBypassed(host);
    }

    public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination) => _wrapped.GetProxy(destination);

    public ICredentials Credentials
    {
        get => _wrapped.Credentials;
        set => _wrapped.Credentials = value;
    }
}
```

Instantiate `FilteredProxy` once before any HTTP request:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new FilteredProxy(wrapped: yourProxy,
                                               useFor: new Regex("YOUR_REGEX_HERE", RegexOptions.Compiled));
```

For more information check:

- [WinHTTP vs. WinINet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinHttp/winhttp-vs-wininet) page on Microsoft Docs
- [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy not compatible with HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7037) .NET Core issue on GitHub
- [Understanding Web Proxy Configuration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/10/11/understanding-web-proxy-configuration/) article by Eric Law